# std::map<,>.emplace() producing error

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I'm using a map to store data parsed from a text file. The actual code is pretty hefty, although I can post it if this isn't enough, but here's the outline of anything that contributes to the line that's causing the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

bool processTXT(char path[])
{
    ifstream source;
    source.open(path);

    char* key = new char[200];
    char* entry = new char[200];

    ifstream.getline(key, 200);
    ifstream.getline(entry, 200);

    //Not quite the original, but close enough; add lots of processing here

    map<string,string> currentBlock(map<string,string>());

    string keyS(string(key));
    string entryS(string(entry));
    currentBlock.emplace(keyS, entryS); //<----- THIS line seems to be the problem

    //Serialisation (of currentBlock) that I have yet to implement

}
```

This causes this compilation error:

```
error C2664: 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair(const std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &)' :
cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> '
to 'const std::string &'
```

I suspect I'm using the wrong one of C++'s million variations on the theme of 'string', but I'm not sure and, if so, I have no idea what I am supposed to be using or how to fix it.

Comment: Does it work with `currentBlock.emplace( std::make_pair( keyS, entryS) );` ?

Comment: What Zhen said, and also you do not need to initialize the map like that. a `map<string,string> currentBlock;` is definitely sufficient.

Comment: @Zhen, you want `currentBlock.emplace( std::make_pair(keyS, entryS) );`

Comment: [Read the documentation for `std::map::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace)

Comment: You've got a lot of double constructions going on. Or you _think_ you do :)

Comment: On unrelated note to the original problem, `ifstream.getline` should read `source.getline`...

Comment: @Zhen It does work indeed. What was the problem, then?

Answer (score 5):

This statement

```
map<string,string> currentBlock(map<string,string>());
```

is a function declaration that has return type  map and one parameter of function type that also has the same return type. .

That it would be clear this construction

```
map<string,string>()
```

is a function declaration with an abstract declarator as a parameter of function .currentBlock.

Write simply

```
map<string,string> currentBlock;
```

The same is valid for lines

```
string keyS(string(key));
string entryS(string(entry));
```

That is they are also function declarations having parameters with namea key and entry of type std::string

Comment: same for `keyS` and `entryS`, you want to surround them by extra parenthesis (or just use `string keyS(key)`, see @LightnessRacesinOrbit 's comment below)

Comment: @vsoftco I have also found this.:)

Comment: sorry I saw just now your update :) I guess he needs the other 2 definitions, as he is constructing 2 strings from 2 C-arrays.

Comment: @vsoftco: No extra parentheses needed: `string keyS(key);` is sufficient in the first place.

Comment: I prefer to use `auto keyS = string(key);` removes duplication of type.

Comment: @Zhen That's utterly silly. `string keyS(key)` has no duplication of type.

Comment: @Zhen one of Herb Sutter's rare not so awesome ideas.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes, I wrong, there is no dup. But I found Herb Sutter's style enjoyable.

Comment: @Zhen: I'm sorry to hear that.

Comment: in C++11 using uniform initialization syntax (ie '{' '}' instead of '(' ')') can alleviate this most vexing parse problem.